# IntelliJ IDEA shows plugin not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to tune IntelliJ IDEA.
In the company I now work they use Nexus as a store for Maven plugins.
In maven settings file (.m2/settings.xml) there are Nexus repositories :

```
.../nexus/content/repositories/releases
.../nexus/content/repositories/releases-temporal/
.../nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
```

In IDEA I see errors like:

```
Plugin '''org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7''' not found
Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems.
```

Though Nexus contains it as I can see through it's web interface.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Is this a problem even if you use maven directly from a command line?

Comment: If I run "mvn install" from console I get no errors and build succeeds.

Comment: How about "mvn project-info-reports:help" ?

Comment: Great, that helped! Plugins have been downloaded to local computer. But what was wrong with Idea or Maven?

Comment: Perhaps intellij is using the wrong settings.xml file. Look in setup and you can see.

Answer (score 6):

IDEA should normally manage your Maven dependencies for you (as long as your pom.xml are correct.)

When your POM-file changes, IDEA will display a notification-window and ask if you would like to download dependencies (this can be easy to miss).

Or, if IDEA is configured with automatic Maven imports (File > Settings > Maven > Importing -> Import Maven projects manually), this should happen automatically.

If your problem persists, you can delete and re-import your IDEA-project:

- Close IDEA.
- Remove "*.iml" and ".idea"-directories.
- Run "mvn clean install" from the command-line.
- Re-import your project into IDEA.

This will normally solve these types of tricky problems.

Also worth checking: If you use Maven, your IDEA (and Eclipse) project files should not need to be checked into version control. If you check out someone elses *.iml-files or .idea-folder, problems can occur.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe try this solution:

Close your IntelliJ IDEA. Backup IDE setting files ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGeuI.png)). Then, delete all files in directory "config":

```
<User home>\.IntelliJIdeaXX\config
```

(on Windows, for example: C:\Users\user_name.IntelliJIdea13\config)

Go to menu File \ Settings or press Ctrl + Alt + Shift, in group Project Settings, choose Maven \ Repositories, press button Add "Artifactory or Nexus Service URLs", choose:

```
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local
```

Then update this repository, you will wait some minutes for indexing repository.
Then try what you want.

[image: Settings]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGeuI.png) http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-and-ide-settings.html